# I want my C# winforms program to copy it self to system32

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made a C# windows forms application and want this application to copy itself (the file of the program) to the system32 of the current system. I want such function:

```
function copyProg() {
   //copy the program to the system32 of current windows version...
   //return the new url
}
```

Comment: Just a question, **WHY** would you want something like that?

Comment: There are so many reasons why this is a bad idea.

Comment: In another question this user asks how to spy on keyboard input to internet browsers. I am personally too skeptical to help anyway.

Comment: Yep, sounds like Malware to me.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized". That's the closest I can come to "too much like malware; no one should ever want to do this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "bad idea" and "frowned upon". A cleaner and more accepted practice is to create an environment variable that points to your applications startup directory.

```
string localPath = Application.StartupPath;
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("EXAMPLE", localPath);
```